# How can I pass a checkbox by reference?

Tags: vb6, pass-by-reference

I've run into what seems to be an odd quirk with VB6. I'm passing a checkbox to a method with the signature `MyMethod(ByRef object)` and calling it as `myClass.MyMethod chkMyCheckbox`. VB6, however, refuses to pass the checkbox itself, but instead passes a reference to `1` to my method. I'm guessing that this has something to do with how VB6 specifies an object's default properties. How can I get the entire object to be passed, not just `.Value`? I cannot turn off default properties, as a large amount of the legacy code relies heavily on them.

[image: Typing discrepancy]

As you can see, `ChkCalFault` is a Checkbox and not an integer, but is being evaluated and passed as its integer value. (Which is in this screenshot `0`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see what your trying to do with the code so I apologize if this is off-base, but would modifying your methods signature to

```
MyMethod(ByRef MyCheckBox as CheckBox)
```

work for you? If not, the undocumented VarPtr will get the address of your checkbox object, but I don't know if that points you in the right direction either.

Comment: This answer may point in the right direction. You do not pass the checkbox as an object here, but as a Variant because you omitted the 'As' part. Try MyMethod(ByRef MyCheckBox as Object)